# th:each loop doesnt work

Tags: html, spring, jpa, thymeleaf

I have problem with th:each. It doesn't looping. I try fix it for long time and I searched many topic with the same problem but it still doesn't work. So I ask  here for info how fix it.

Nothing display from the list (First and Second) on webpage so i think that with this is something wrong

```
<ul th:each="author : ${book.authors}">
```

Book class:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "books")
     private Set<Author> authors = new HashSet<>();
```

Author class:

```
@ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "author_books",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name= "author_id"))
    private Set<Book> books = new HashSet<>();
```

HTML code:

```
<td>
    <ul th:each="author : ${book.authors}">
        <li>First</li>
        <li>Second</li>
        <li  th:text="${book.getAuthorsN()}">Author</li>
    </ul>
</td>`
```

=======UPDATE=======

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class BooksController {

private final BookService bookService;

public BooksController(BookService bookService) {
    this.bookService = bookService;
}

@RequestMapping("/books/home")
public String showBooks(Model model){

    model.addAttribute("books", bookService.getBooks());

    return "books/home";
}
```

}

Comment: and what does your DEBUGGING tell you? data is retrieved from the database correctly? looked at the log of the JPA provider?

Comment: Okay, debugging tell me that mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property so i change 

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authors")

to 

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "books")

but still doesnt work and debugging now dont show any errors

Comment: Add your controller

Comment: Okay, controller added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get displayed the `book`'s properties (like `getAuthorsN()`), you should iterate through the `books` list, not the `authors`, e.g.:

```
<ul th:each="book : ${author.books}">
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li th:text="${book.getAuthorsN()}">Author</li>
</ul>
```

Also probably in your `Author` class you should change object's primary key (`joinColumns`), and a foreign key to the target object's primary key (`inverseJoinColumns`) to hold the relationship between `Author` and `Book`:

```
@JoinTable(name = "author_books",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "author_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name= "book_id"))
```

Read more about [`ManyToMany relationship`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany).